# Avoid ajax from showing session messages before redirect (magento 2)

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I ensure to display session messages after redirect?

When I add session messages to observer they were displayed on same page before redirect because on that page there is ajax used (checkout). After that messages are deleted from session and after redirect there is nothing displayed.